# CakePHP: Paginate on Contained Array

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination

I have `Categories` associated to many `Products` but a Product can only have one category.

In my Category view, I have a list of all products assign to that particular category and outputted into a table. I'm trying to paginate this table, since it can easily grow in size.

My CategoriesController, View action:

```
  public function admin_view($id=null) {
    if (!$id) {$this->redirect('/admin/categories');}

    $category = $this->Category->find('first', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'Category.id' => $id
        ),
        'contain' => array('Product')
    ));

    if(!$category) {
        $this->redirect('/admin/categories');
    } else {
        $this->set('category', $category);
    }
```

- Category Model: `public $hasMany = array('Product');`
- Product Model:
  `public $belongsTo = 'Category';`

This outputs the data with a Category array with all the Category data and a Products array with all the Products associated with this particular Category:
[image]

**Question:** How can I paginate the Products list that I have as a table in my Categories Admin_View view?

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->Paginator->settings = array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Category.id' => $id
    ),
    'contain' => array('Product'),
    'limit' => 25
);

$category = $this->paginate('Category');
```

Comment: Did this work as expected? Reading the code makes it look like it will try and return 25 Categories where the id = $id along with their contained Products (which would end up as 1 Category and all its Products). Can some explanation be added to the answer?

Comment: this only paginates Category, not products